# SSIS Fast Load error when using Attunity Oracle connector to 11g

Tags: oracle, ssis, oracle11g

When enabling **Fast Load** in Attunity Oracle Destination Components in several similar SSIS packages using **Oracle 11g** as target - a **few packages fail** and return the error below, but the rest of them work fine.

The **error message** I get is:

> Description: Fast Load error encountered during PreLoad or Setup
>   phase.     Text:      ORA-39826: Direct path load of view or synonym (
>   TABLE_NAME ) could not be resolved.

- If I'll disable the Fast Load, those that failed would work fine too of course.
- More importantly, the failing packages **work fine with Fast Load when using Oracle 10g as target**.

I don't understand why it doesn't work in those that failed.

What am I missing? What should I do to make the Fast Load work at all times and not sometimes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By pure chance, I discovered that the target component fails in an SSIS package if its ‘TableName’ property contains **spaces before or after**(!) the name of the table. Once deleted it works fine.
This error didn’t occur on 10g.

Answer (score 0):

probably a driver issue.

The 'fast load' option internally uses a BULK INSERT statement for uploading data into the destination table instead of a simple INSERT statement for each single row. Since bulk insert is a native sql server function you should try to understand how does it work for oracle. It probably changed from 10g to 11g

Comment: Thanks, following your answer I've checked with our DBA, but he said that he already installed all of the relevant Oracle patches.
In addition, I've talked to Attunity's support but they said that the issue is relevant to Microsoft.